# rpmbuild failing in repo with 'error=13, permission denied' in maven build

Tags: linux, spring, maven, devops, rpm

little issue here..

in ~/user/work_dir/config-service (<-bitbucket repo clone) & run `sudo mvn clean install`

error;

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.5:attached-rpm (generate-rpm) on project config-service: Unable to build the RPM: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "rpmbuild" (in directory "/home/ec2-user/work_dir/config-service/target/rpm/config-service/SPECS"): error=13, Permission denied -> [Help 1]
```

today I `sudo yum install rpm-build`  & it looks like it installed okay.

I added `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/rpm` thinking maybe that might be the issue..

any guesses or advice please?  . . . .thank you everyone